# How to update MongoDb document using python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have 2 documents in a collection with a structure like below. I want to update "Source" as Home where environment is "QA" and Name is "Alan".

```
{
  environment: DevA,
  data: [
   { 
     Name: "John",
     Source: "Home"
   },
   { 
     Name: "Alan",
     Source: "Office"
   },
   { 
     Name: "Susan",
     Source: "Office"
   }
  ],
},
{
  environment: DevB,
  data: [
   { 
     Name: "John",
     Source: "Home"
   },
   { 
     Name: "Alan",
     Source: "Office"
   },
   { 
     Name: "Susan",
     Source: "Office"
   }
  ],
}
```

I tried the following code below. But it did not update it, neither gave an error.

```
 collection1.update_one({ 'environment':'QA', 'data.Name':'Alan'},
                          { $'set': {
                                     "data":"Source":"NewValue"
                                    }
                          })
```

Comment: Possibly because you have spelled environment as environemnt? Although I suspect that would raise an error.

Comment: umm, no. That's a typo here in question only. I'll correct. May be I have given multiple filter condn.. Could that be issue?

Comment: When you say that you have a document with a structure shown in the question, does that represent two different documents?  In either case, those documents do not match the condition of `environment: 'QA'` so it would make sense that no update was performed if that was the data the operation was tested against.  To your overall question - you'll probably want to look into `arrayFilters` since you want to manipulate the `data` array.  See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-array-elements-that-match-arrayfilters)

Comment: @user20042973 I am able to do it for one nested array [answer posted below] in the document say for name = "Alan" using below answer. However, I also want to update for more than one nested arrays elements like for where name="Alan" *& name="John", update source as "Office".

Comment: Great, looks like we're making progress! Two thoughts regarding your latest comment and the answer, the first is that you don't need `$elemMatch` here if you are only searching a single field (`Name`) in the `data` array. You'd only need it if you added a second field in there. The second thing is to search for multiple names you probably want `$in`. So the second predicate should probably change to `'data.Name': { $in: [ "Alan", "John" ] }`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to update it using following code:

```
collection1.update_one( 
{
  "environment":"DevB",
  "data" {"$elemMatch": { "Name": "Alan"} }
},
{
  "$set" : {
          "data.$.source":"ABC"
           }   
 })
```